# inserting a substring into another string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, null-character

**i just started learning c**. i am doing an exercise and the question is as follows.

Write a function called `insertString` to insert one character string into another string.The arguments to the function should consist of the source string, the string to be inserted, and the position in the source string where the string is to be inserted. So, the call `insertString (text, "per", 10);` with text as originally defined `"the wrong son"` results in the character string `"per"` being inserted inside text, beginning at `text[10]`.Therefore, the character string `"the wrong person"` is stored inside the text array after the function returned.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int insertString(char[],char[],int);
int stringLength(char[]);
int main()
{
  char text[]="the wrong son";
  int result=insertString(text,"per",10);
  if(result!=-1)
    printf("string 1 is : %s \n",text);
  else
    printf("Not possible\n");
  return 0;
}
int insertString(char a[],char b[],int pos)
{
  int i=0,j=0;
  int lengthA=stringLength(a);
  int lengthB=stringLength(b);
  if(pos>lengthA)
    return -1;

  for(i=lengthA;i>=pos;i--)
      a[i+lengthB]=a[i];

  for ( i = 0; i < lengthB; ++i )
      a[i + pos] = b[i];

  return 1;
}
int stringLength(char x[])
{
  int length=0;
  while(x[length]!='\0')
    length++;
  return length;
}
```

i have done this and it's working too. but i am receiving a message `abort trap : 6`. when i looked upon it, i learned it's an error because i am writing to the memory that i don't own. since i have used variable length character arrays, wherever the `null character` is, indicates the end of array and i am trying to extending it by inserting a string, that's my understanding. am i right so far?

i am also moving the `null character`. i don't know whether it's right or wrong.

so is there a way to get around this error? Also, **i don't know pointers yet and they're in the next chapter of the textbook** .

Any help in this would be appreciated very much.

Comment: You're not using "variable length character arrays". You either have to allocate enough space for your final result in advance, or you have to use allocated memory and possibly reallocate it. Look up references to `malloc()` and `realloc()`;

Comment: "i have used variable length character arrays" where? `char a[]` in the function header is not a variable length array.

Comment: oh is it? @Logicrat . in the textbook it's given that the character arrays that end with `null character` are variable length character arrays

Comment: @n.m. it was mentioned like that in the textbook that any character array that ends with a `null character` is a variable length character arrays. that's why i thought i am using them all this time

Comment: Your textbook is using non-standard terminology and misleading definitions. Complain.

Comment: alright. thank you @n.m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable-length array is a [very specific C construct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) that has nothing to do with what your textbook calls "variable length arrays". If I were you I would not trust this textbook if it said that 1+1=2. So much for it.

A character array that ends with a null character is called *string* by pretty much everyone, everywhere.

```
char text[]="the wrong son";
```

Your textbook led you to believe that `text` will hold as many characters as you need. Alas, there is no such thing in C. In fact `text` will hold exactly as many characters as there are in its initializer, plus 1 for the null terminator, so you cannot insert anything in it.

In order for your program to work, you need to explicitly allocate as many characters for `text` as the *resulting string* will contain.

So as there are 14 characters in "the wrong son" (including the terminator) and three characters in "per" (not including the terminator), you need 17 characters in total:

```
char text[17]="the wrong son";
```

You can also check your calculations:

```
int result=insertString(text, "per", 10, sizeof(text));
...
int insertString(char a[], char b[], int pos, int capacity)
{
   ...
   if (lengthA + lengthB + 1 < capacity) 
     return -1;
   ...
```

Comment: thank you very much @n.m. until now i am in a wrong notion. that cleared things for me now.

Answer (score 0):

**First you must understand what the difference between C-programming and other programming languages are manual memory management and pointers.**

In C you have to do everything yourself but you have total control of everything, in other languages like Java a lot is made automatically for you but you can't open the hood.

Memory handling in C is the essence of C and is very different from for instance Java that looks very alike C. Java and C syntax are very much alike, but in two completely different worlds.
C++ is an extension of C that allow similar features like in Java, but still memory wise is C.

There are two types of memory in C:

- Automatic string array (declared as char xx[]) with the exact length of its initialization number or defined string length (the number between the []) + 1 (for null termination), can't be changed.
- Dynamic memory (declared as char*) is allocated with calloc() or alloc() and can be changed in length with realloc() and must be manually freed or else the program will leak memory (still allocate memory after the program is ended (some OS has automatic clean-up of that but it is bad style C programming not freeing memory)).

Dynamic memory is delivered to a pointer (char*) that points to the memory allocated. Pointers can point at any type of memory also string arrays and even integers.

A pointer is an integer, a number pointing at the available memory address in the OS, the OS keep track of the memory of each pointer, but do not clean it up like in Java.
Also note that after the realloc the old memory of the old pointer is freed by the command, new is allocated that you must manually free, later after use.

It is possible to send a pointer (it is just a number) into a function and the function changes the pointer (it is just another number pointing at memory (that might not be the same)).
Because of this it is essential to return the new pointer from functions that might have changed its content.

In practice the core of C-programming is pointer programming and the programmer must have a firm track of the memory or the program goes berserk, you have to learn the routines.

With pointer programming it is possible to have absolute control over all the memory and the functions becomes normally very efficient, fast and memory lean.
This is used also when we are talking about huge data like in high resolution pictures or video content, and often the only way to get performance.

**Extended level - pointer to pointers**

When getting more advanced it is possible to send the pointer of a pointer (char**) to a function allowing the function to amend the content of a pointer like reallocation of a string and the updated pointer will be readable by the calling function. This way multiple pointers can be amended (there is only one return value).
A pointer to a pointer, points to the memory where the pointer address (the number that points to the memory) is stored, so sending it into the function the function can change the pointers number (what memory it points at) and the calling function can read it (the same pointer have a new value).

Pointers to pointers are normally used for instance in database programming with linked lists being able to control a huge number of memory chunks in a long chain, and being able to handle them smoothly.

Most other programming languages basic system is programmed in C, so normally it is possible to integrate chunks of C--code to improve performance.
ANSI C is the same in all computers so it is also a way of making code real portable from system to system and work the same in them all.

**Lets check out your case, here is a sample code to show.**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char* insertString(
    char* pTarget,
    char* pInput);

void main(void)
{
    char Target[9] = { "Hello" };
    char Target2[9] = { "Hi" };
    char Input[] = { " World" };
```

Target and Target2 are automatic string arrays with the exact length of its initialization number, the number between the[] and Input is defined by the string length(+1 for null termination), can't be changed.

So, the length of Input is defined as 7 bytes, six letters +1, as Target and Target2 are defined as 9 bytes (can contain 8 letters), can't be changed, they are string arrays.

This below will not work, because Target is too short, only 9 chars space (enough for 8 letters) and Target + Input is 11 letters, the program will crash.

```
    strcat(Target, Input);
```

But this will work because Target2 is 9 chars (space for 8 letters) and Target2 + Input is 8 letters, so it fits.

```
    strcat(Target2, Input);
    printf("%s\n", Target2);
```

This below will not work because Target is an automatic char array with the exact length of its initialization number or string length +1 (for null termination), its length can't be changed.
They are fixed in length and not possible to extend or shrink in length, can't realloc them, and they will be freed automatically at the end of the function.
In fact, it is created normally in another set of memory than the dynamic memory and is protected from change.

```
    pTarget = insertString(Target, Input);

    {
```

This below will work because it is dynamically allocated memory(by a calloc or alloc command) that can be reallocated to any size.
Dynamic memory(volatile) in C is not automatic like in other programming languages, must be taken care of manually.

Usually in C a p is put ahead for pointers to differentiate them from automatic string arrays.
Dynamically allocated memory must be manually freed after use or the program will leak memory, it is not Java with auto clean - up.

```
        char* pTarget = calloc(strlen(Target) + 1, sizeof(char));
        if (pTarget) {
            strcpy(pTarget, Target);
            pTarget = insertString(pTarget, Input);
```

Also notice you as a programmer must check that you got the memory you asked for by the memory allocation command calloc.
If not (very unlikely memory is unavailable in 2022) you can't perform the action and, you fail, or the program will crash.

```
            printf("%s\n", pTarget);
            free(pTarget);
        }
        else
            printf("%s\n", "Failure!");
    }
}

char* insertString(
    char* pTarget,
    char* pInput)
{
```

We are here reallocating the memory to get it enlarged to fit our use

```
    pTarget = realloc(pTarget, (strlen(pTarget) + strlen(pInput) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

The old memory is freed by realloc and a new larger is allocated for us.
Now the pointer (the number that points to memory) might not be the same as before realloc.
A pointer is a storage of the number and the same storage pTarget contains the new number to the new data, OK.

```
    if (pTarget)
        strcat(pTarget, pInput);
    return pTarget;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int replace_substring (char *str, char *substr, char *new_substr) {
    int pos = delete_substring (str, substr);   /* first delete the existing substring      */
    if (pos == -1) return pos;                  /* substring not found, return                  */
    insert_substring (str, pos, new_substr);    /* add the new substring at the deleted position */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

int replace_substring (char *str, char *substr, char *new_substr) {
int pos = delete_substring (str, substr); /*first delete the existing substring*/
if (pos == -1) return pos;               /*substring not found, return*/
insert_substring (str, pos, new_substr); /*add the new substring at the deleted position*/
}

Comment: When wanting an answer a bit changed, do not post another answer: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74167791/edit) it.